# expected primary-expression before 'char'

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char* chars[26] = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"};
    int a;
    char x;

    while (a < 26) {
        x = char* chars[a];
        a = a + 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

On the line where it says `x = char* chars[a];` an error keeps popping up saying:

> "expected primary-expression before 'char'"

I have searched everywhere, used different kinds of solutions, but they don't work. 
I am new to c++ and this is only my second project....
Also, this:

```
    x = *char[a];
```

or

```
    x = chars[a][0];
```

does remove the errors but when I do:

```
    cout << x;
```

It doesn't show the value of x. So, I am unsure if it works or not.

Comment: As you want to access the first character of the a-th element of the array, use: `x = chars[a][0]`; that's all. Don't forget to initialize `a`.

Comment: Syntax `x = char* chars[a];` is incorrect. Where did you find that syntax? What did you expect it to do?

Comment: as i said i am new to c++ and i kinda got that from python.

Comment: Rather than getting things from python - which is a completely different language - try reading up on C++.    Try using `x = chars[a][0]` or `x = *chars[a]`.

Comment: @Jean-Baptiste Yunès ok, the error stopped appearing, but when i do cout<<x; it doesn't show x

Comment: @BlackHawkCH91It seems to be another question... Open another if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char chars[26] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
    int a=0;
    char x;

    while (a < 26) {
        x = chars[a];
        a = a + 1;
    }

return 0;
```

}

it's a single quote because it's a char not a string,
and you should initialize a with 0 so it doesn't contain garbage.